Resolving contradiction with energy conservation for simple pendulum
Say we have a simple pendulum, where the string has length $1$ and the object hanging from the string has mass $m$. Let's say the string initially hangs vertically down when the object has initial speed $v_0 > 0$ to the right. Say $v_0 \ll 1$.
If I did my calculations correctly, the horizontal component of the acceleration is $$a(x) = -gx\sqrt{1-x^2} \tag{1};$$ indeed, at angle $\theta$, we have $x = \sin\theta$ and the force to the left is of magnitude $T\sin\theta = mg\sin\theta\cos\theta$ (where $T$ is the tension force, and equals $mg\cos\theta$ in order to balance with the component of the gravitational force that is parallel to the string).
One can derive from $(1)$ that $$v(x) = \sqrt{\frac{2g(1-x^2)^{3/2}-(2g-3v_0^2)}{3}} \tag{2};$$ indeed, one way to verify $(2)$ is to differentiate both sides with respect to $t$ and see the result is $(1)$, and note that $(2)$ is valid at $x=0$.
My issue is that $(2)$ seems to indicate that $v(x)$ is positive all the way until $$\widehat{x}_f = \sqrt{1-\biggl(1-\frac{3v_0^2}{2g}\biggr)^{2/3}}.$$ But the basic conservation of energy argument indicates $$x_f = \sqrt{1-\biggl(1-\frac{v_0^2}{2g}\biggr)^2};$$ indeed, $\frac{1}{2}mv_0^2 = mgh_f$ yields $h_f = \frac{v_0^2}{2g}$, and $x_f = \sqrt{1-(1-h_f)^2}$.
For small $v_0 > 0$, it holds that $\widehat{x}_f > x_f$, which seems impossible to me, since then $v(x_f) > 0$, contradicting that $x$ decreases after reaching $x_f$.
I would appreciate any help resolving this (I tried for a while before asking)!

Thanks to Mike1994's answer, I fixed the physics and now have derived the valid formula for the velocity, allowing to recover the result that $x_f = \sqrt{1-\biggl(1-\frac{v_0^2}{2g}\biggr)^2}$ (without appealing to energy directly).
The centripetal acceleration is $v^2$ (we are assuming length $1$ string), whilst the tangential acceleration is $g\sin\theta$. Therefore, the horizontal component of the acceleration is $v^2\sin\theta+g\sin\theta\cos\theta$, pointing to the left. Therefore, $$-a(x) = v^2\frac{x}{1-x^2}+gx\sqrt{1-x^2},$$ which admits $$v(x) = \sqrt{2g(1-x^2)^{3/2}-(2-v_0^2)(1-x^2)},$$ which is $0$ when $x = \sqrt{1-\biggl(1-\frac{v_0^2}{2g}\biggr)^2}$!
One comment is that I don't know how to derive $v(x)$ from $a(x)$ besides guess-and-check. For deriving $(2)$ from $(1)$, I initially used $t''(x) = -a(x)\bigl(t'(x)\bigr)^3$ to solve for $t'(x)$, but I can't make use of that with the correct equation for $a(x)$.

Your crucial mistake is early on. You claim that the tension $T$ is equal to the component of gravity parallel to the string $mg \: \text{cos}(\theta)$, but this is incorrect because the pendulum bob is moving on a curved path, and at any given time the net radial force needs to be centripetal so that $$T \:- mg\: \text{cos}(\theta)=\frac{mv^2}{r}$$
You are trying to reduce this problem to 1-D, which is possible, but it is fundamentally 2D so you should start fully 2-D with everybody. You can work in cartesian coordinates, but you need to look at the horizontal $\textit{and}$ vertical motion at the same time, or work in polar coordinates as is more typical. For projectiles or other unconstrained motion, these two components of motion are unrelated, but a situation like this with a $\textit{constraint}$ like being on a string or a curved ramp means that your x-motion and y-motion are now dependent on each-other (a definite change in x- corresponds to a definite change in y).

Thanks! Though I of course acknowledged the $2$-D nature of the problem, looking along one axis to (falsely) claim $T = mg\cos\theta$ and then looking another to make a (false) claim about the horizontal component of the acceleration. My mistake was assuming the acceleration was only tangential and not centripetal at all.

I agree you did treat it 2D- just not 2D enough haha!

Thanks again! I edited my main question to include the correct derivation now (and it all occurs in 1-D! :) )
